# Flattening a List of List to a List with Java 8 stream API

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have the following code which could be much simpler using Java 8 stream API:

```
List<List<String>> listOfListValues;
public List<String> getAsFlattenedList() {
        List<String> listOfValues= new ArrayList<>();
        for (List<String> value: listOfListValues) {
            listOfValues.add(String.valueOf(value));
        }
        return listOfValues;
    }
```

I searched for a solution on SO and found this:

```
listOfListValues.stream()
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But this doesn't do the same what I want.

Comment: No need to use `flatmap`. Detailed answer below.  Like and accept whichever you find useful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You require only a "simple" `map` here:

```
List<List<String>> listOfListValues;
public List<String> getAsFlattenedList() {
    return listOfListValues.stream()
            .map(String::valueOf)
            .collect(toList());
}
```

`flatMap` is rather used to transform one `Stream` to another, which makes sense if you need more entries or less then currently available (or just a newly mapped `Stream` to filter/map/etc it further down), e.g.:

- count all the unique strings of all lists:

  ```
  listOfListValues.stream()
                  .flatMap(List::stream) // we want to count all, also those from the "inner" list...
                  .distinct()
                  .count()
  ```
- truncate entries after a certain size:

  ```
  listOfListValues.stream()
          .flatMap(list -> {
              if (list.size() > 3) // in this case we use only some of the entries
                  return Stream.concat(list.subList(0, 2).stream(), Stream.of("..."));
              else
                  return list.stream();
          })
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
  ```
- flattening values of a map for several interested keys:

  ```
  Map<Key, List<Value>> map = new HashMap<>();
  Stream<Value> valueStream = interestedKeys.stream()
                                            .map(map::get)
                                            .flatMap(List::stream);
  ```

Answer (score 4):

No need to use flatmap.

```
listOfListValues.stream()
        .map(String::valueOf)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Explanation:**
The `flatMap` function combines a `map` and a `flat` operation. This is not needed.  Flattening means converting something like `[ [1,2,3],[4,5,6,7],[8,9] ]` to `[ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 ]` i.e. converting a 2D array to a 1D array.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like so,

```
listOfListValues.stream().map(List::toString).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: If I try to print your list like this: System.out.println(listOfLists.stream().map(List::toString).collect(Collectors.toList()));  I get the following output:   [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [10, 20, 30, 40], [100, 200, 300, 400]]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a flatMap here:

```
  List<List<Integer>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<>();
    listOfLists.add(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5));
    listOfLists.add(Arrays.asList(10,20,30,40));
    listOfLists.add(Arrays.asList(100,200,300,400));

    System.out.println(listOfLists);

    List<Integer> collect = listOfLists.stream().flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(collect);
```

And the output is:
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [10, 20, 30, 40], [100, 200, 300, 400]]

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 100, 200, 300, 400]

Answer (score 0):

I use reduce operation on stream for this:

```
var b = List.of(5, 6, 7, 8);
var a = List.of(1, 2, 3, 4);
var c = List.of(a, b);
var res = c.stream().reduce(new ArrayList<>(), (r, l) -> {
  r.addAll(l);
  return r;
});
```